# Join Query not working in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, inner-join

I am executing an `inner-join` query using `hibernate-session.createQuery()` and I got the error:

```
Feb 21, 2014 5:22:07 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 1:151: unexpected token: on
Feb 21, 2014 5:22:07 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 1:151: unexpected token: on
line 1:151: unexpected token: on
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.fromJoin(HqlBaseParser.java:1693)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.fromClause(HqlBaseParser.java:1348)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectFrom(HqlBaseParser.java:1054)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:700)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:294)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1649)
    at com.sanyasi.masterDataActions.ModifyDistrictsAction.display(ModifyDistrictsAction.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:292)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:255)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
```

My Query is :

```
select dist.districtName, dist.status, stat.stateName from sa_district_master dist inner join sa_state_master stat on dist.stateId = stat.stateId
```

But, if I am executing the same Query on my-sql console, it executes perfectly and giving O/P:

```
+--------------+--------+-----------+
| districtName | status | stateName |
+--------------+--------+-----------+
| Hisar        | 0      | HARYANA   |
| Gurgaon      | 0      | HARYANA   |
| Ambala       | 0      | HARYANA   |
| Rohtak       | 0      | HARYANA   |
| Sirsa        | 0      | HARYANA   |
+--------------+--------+-----------+
```

My Hibernate code:

```
try{
        hibernateSession = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        if(hibernateSession != null){
            Query query = hibernateSession.createQuery("select dist.districtName, dist.status, stat.stateName from sa_district_master dist inner join sa_state_master stat on dist.stateId = stat.stateId");
            List list = query.list();
            for (Object object : list) {
                Object[] objArray = (Object[])object;
                System.out.println("Obj : " + objArray[0]);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        hibernateSession.flush();
        hibernateSession.close();
    }
```

I didn't understand why I'm getting the error...

plzzz help...

> (Please tell me if anything else you want)

Comment: Change `hibernateSession.createQuery` to `hibernateSession.createSQLQuery`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query seems to be more like a standard SQL query than a HQL query. Use the [`Session#createSQLQuery(String sqlQuery)`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#createSQLQuery%28java.lang.String%29) method to create a SQL query like this.

```
Query query = hibernateSession.createSQLQuery("select dist.districtName, dist.status, stat.stateName from sa_district_master dist inner join sa_state_master stat on dist.stateId = stat.stateId");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Query query = hibernateSession.createSQLQuery("select dist.districtName, dist.status, stat.stateName from sa_district_master dist inner join sa_state_master stat on dist.stateId = stat.stateId");
```

use .createSQLQuery method for mysql

Answer (score 1):

You are using a SQL query, so you need to create a [SQLQuery](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#querysql-creating)

```
try{
    hibernateSession = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    if(hibernateSession != null){
        Query query = hibernateSession.createSQLQuery("select dist.districtName, dist.status, stat.stateName from sa_district_master dist inner join sa_state_master stat on dist.stateId = stat.stateId");
        List list = query.list();
        for (Object object : list) {
            Object[] objArray = (Object[])object;
            System.out.println("Obj : " + objArray[0]);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally {
    hibernateSession.flush();
    hibernateSession.close();
}
```