# INNER JOIN not working in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, join

I have a `oneToMany` association between Movie and actor Table and a `ManyToOne` association reverse way. One JOIN works but when I have a filter clause in JOIN it fails. please find the relevant code sections with comments above it describing it.

I have read this post. But this did not help
[Join Query not working in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933876/join-query-not-working-in-hibernate)

Here are the relevant parts in my Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Movie {
    ......
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="movie",fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Actor> actors=new HashSet<>();
    //getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Actor {
    .....
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="ACTOR_MOVIE")
    //getters and setters
}
```

Here is my HibernateTest class:

```
public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Movie movie1 = new Movie("Mr and Mrs.Smith", new Date(2005, 6, 5));
        Actor actor3=new Actor("Brad");
        actor3.setMovie(movie1);
        Actor actor4=new Actor("Joe"); 
        actor4.setMovie(movie1); 
        movie1.getActors().add(actor3);
        movie1.getActors().add(actor4);

        Movie movie = new Movie("Titanic", new Date(1997,12,19));
        Actor actor1=new Actor("Leo");
        Actor actor2=new Actor("Kate");
        actor1.setMovie(movie);
        actor2.setMovie(movie); 
        movie.getActors().add(actor1); 
        movie.getActors().add(actor2); 

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(movie);
        session.persist(movie1);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        //The following query works
        //List<Object[]> actor_from_movies=session.createQuery("select m.name,act.name from Movie m INNER JOIN m.actors act").list();

        //This throws error        
        List<Object[]> actor_from_movies=session.createQuery("select m.name,act.name from Movie m INNER JOIN m.actors act"
                + "where act.name=:acname").setParameter("acname", "Brad").list();

       System.out.println("actor_from_movies "+ actor_from_movies);

       session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
}
```

ERROR message:

```
Sep 30, 2014 11:08:42 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 1:92: unexpected token: act
Sep 30, 2014 11:08:42 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 1:92: unexpected token: act
line 1:92: unexpected token: act
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.fromJoin(HqlBaseParser.java:1727)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.fromClause(HqlBaseParser.java:1380)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectFrom(HqlBaseParser.java:1086)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:731)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
    at com.example.hibernate.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:142)

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: act near line 1, column 92 [select m.name,act.name from com.example.hibernate.dto.Movie m INNER JOIN m.actors actwhere act.name=:acname]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
    at com.example.hibernate.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:142)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a blank before where:

```
" where act.name=:acname").
```

Comment: good catch. wondering how you figured that out..from Error message?

Comment: @brainstorm Yes. If you show to this part of the message `INNER JOIN m.actors actwhere act.name=:acname` you can see that `act` and  `where`are connected.

Comment: Thanks good one! On a related note, is it possible to do this query without JOIN. i.e `session.createQuery("select m.name,act.name from Movie m, m.actors act where "BRAD" IN act.names").list()` . Ofcourse, this did not work, but wondering if it is possible without JOIN? Thanks

Comment: @brainstorm What should  that be `"BRAD" IN act.names`?

Comment: I have movie objects. I can pull out all the actors objects from each movie object and then filter each movie for actor with name "BRAD". (Actor class has field called name).

Comment: @brainstorm Sounds like you need an exists, but i am not sure if it is possible  in hql.